# Multi character constant warning for escaped \t

Tags: c, putchar

If I write `putchar('\\t');` while trying to print `"\t"` instead of an actual tab, I get the multi character constant warning. On the other hand, if I write `putchar('\\');` I get no warning. Upon looking in the ASCII table, there is no character `'\\'`, only `'\'`. So why is there no warning? Why is `'\\'` one character but `'\\t'` is more than one? Can a backslash only be used to escape one following character?

Comment: Look up *escape sequence*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\` is one character, `t` is one character, so that is clearly two characters.

`\\` is an escape sequence, just like `\t`; it means `\`.

If you want to print the two characters `\` and `t`, you clearly need either two calls to `putch()` or a function that takes a *string* argument `"\\t"`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences

Answer (score 2):

You *cannot* print `\` and `t` with one `putchar` invocation, since `putchar` puts **one** and exactly only one character into the standard output. Use 2:

```
putchar('\\');
putchar('t');
```

Another option would be to use the **string** `"\\t"` with `fputs`:

```
fputs("\\t", stdout);
```

---

There is no warning for `'\\'` because that is one way how you enter the character literal for the character `\`. On ASCII this is synonymous with `'\134'` and `'\x5c'`.

From [C11 6.4.4.4](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4) paragraphs 2 and 4:

> **2**
>
> An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed in single-quotes, as in `'x'`. [...] With a few exceptions detailed later, the elements of the sequence are any members of the source character set; they are mapped in an implementation-defined manner to members of the execution character set.
>
> [...]
>
> **4**
>
> The double-quote `"` and question-mark `?` are representable either by themselves or by the escape sequences `\"` and `\?`, respectively, but the single-quote `'` and the backslash `\` **shall be represented, respectively, by the escape sequences `\'` and `\\`.**

---

The reason why you get a warning for this is that the behaviour is wholly implementation-defined. In [C11 J.3.4](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.3.4) the following is listed as implementation-defined behaviour:

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte execution character (6.4.4.4).

Since `'\\'` contains an escape sequence that maps to a single-byte execution character `\`, there is no implementation-defined pitfalls, and nothing to warn about; but `\\t` contains 2 characters: `\` and `t`, and it wouldn't do what you want portably.